# upload image in nodejs package

Tags: node.js, npm, image-uploading, getdirectories

i am a developer of nodejs and i am a new one, i want to upload a image in node js and i've done R&D on it on google for nodejs package but everywhere i found complex methods with express which i am not able to understand as i am new to nodejs development.

now the task i want to done is to upload a image using nodejs any package on a specific directory so that i can retrieve it later, please let me know any easy method to achieve this task, i'll be very thankful.

Note: i am not using express or anything i am simply developing in nodejs using sequelize some time, also i don't want to use PHP i just want to have this functionality using HTML in .ejs file and js or with any package.

Thanks.

Comment: refer this http://tonyspiro.com/uploading-and-resizing-an-image-using-node-js/

Comment: some of the packages in your link are not getting installed, like fx-exta or quickthumb